# Proof to go broke almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose you play a game where you start with capital $K_0 = 1$. In each turn $i = 1,2, \dots, n$ you throw a fair coin independently of the history. If you get "heads", you get back $3/2$ of your capital, if you get "tails" you only get back $1/2$ of your capital.

Prove that $K_n \to 0$ almost surely.

My attempt:
First define $R_i$ by $$R_i(\omega) = \begin{cases} \frac{3}{2} & \omega_i = \text{heads} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \omega_i = \text{tails}\end{cases}$$
and note that $K_n = \prod_{i=1}^nR_i $,  $\mathbb E[R_i] = 1 $ and by independence $\mathbb E[K_n] = 1.$ Now the only ways to prove almost sure convergence I know of are the Strong Law of Large Numbers and the Borel-Cantelli Lemma. A way to apply the former is to look at $$\log K_n = \sum \log(R_i).$$
By the Strong Law I get $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log(R_i) \to \log \left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)$$
but that is not quite what I want. Also I find this pretty counterintuitive.

Comment: What’s with the questions concerning coin tosses? This is, I think, the third time within $5$ minutes.

Comment: Very interesting topic I suppose? :D

Comment: Hahaha :)) ${}$

Comment: There is something wrong in your original logic.  After two tosses, $E(K_2)=\frac{13}{16}$, not 1.  If you change $R_i$ to have the values 2 or 0, $E(R_I)=1$, but you will definitely end as soon as you get a tail, irrespective of the number of heads.

Comment: @herb steinberg: How do you compute \frac{13}{16}; after two rounds there are four possible scenarios (each with probability $\frac14$), these are \begin{align*} \frac12 \times \frac12 & = \frac14 \\ \frac12 \times \frac32 & = \frac34 \\ \frac32 \times \frac12 &= \frac34 \\ \frac32 \times \frac32 & = \frac94 \end{align*} where i denoted $\text{(first game outcome)} \times \text{(second game outcome)}$. These sum to $\frac{16}{4}$, which on dividing by 4 (i.e. each occurs with probability $\frac14$), gives $1$.

Comment: I made a mistake (forgot to double the middle term).  A more important note.  Even though the mean stays 1 as a function of n, the median -> 0, specifically after 2n steps the median is at $(\frac{3}{4})^n$.  This should give a clue as to how to prove $K_n \to 0$.

Comment: You are almost there: you know that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log(R_i) \to \log \left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)\approx-0.14$$ almost surely, in particular, $$\sum_{i=1}^n \log(R_i) \leqslant-0.1n$$ for every $n$ large enough, almost surely, in particular, $$\sum_{i=1}^n \log(R_i) \to-\infty$$ almost surely, which is equivalent to $$\prod_{i=1}^n R_i \to0$$ almost surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, firstly I will explain the error in your approach via the strong law, and the correct way in which the Strong Law does suggest this to be true.

However, I think you still need to be careful with this approach, so then present an argument via Martingales.

**Intuition via the strong law**

Your intuition to take logarithms, show almost sure convergence of these, and then exponentiate again is reasonable. This implicitly relies on the [Continuous Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem), which says under certain conditions on a function $g$ then

$$ X_n \xrightarrow{a.s} X \, \Rightarrow \, g(X_n) \xrightarrow{a.s.} g(X).$$

So in this context the sequence $X_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \log R_k$, and $g(x) = \exp(x)$.

The strong law requires us to divide $X_n$ by $n$ to be able to make a statement about the limit. i.e. the strong law states
$$ \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \log R_k \xrightarrow{a.s.} \log \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

But now when we apply the continuous mapping theorem this gives
$$
\exp \left( \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \log R_k  \right) \xrightarrow{a.s.}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

At this point the rest of my proof becomes heuristic: and I think you need to do some serious thinking as to whether it can be justified. If we take powers of $n$ on both sides then we have **in some heuristic sense**
$$
K_n = \exp \left(  \sum_{k=1}^n \log R_k  \right) \xrightarrow{a.s.}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n \rightarrow 0,$$
since $\sqrt{3} < 2$. However this is not rigorous!

**Using Doob's Convergence Theorem**

An alternate, rigorous approach is to first show that $K_n$ is a [Martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)), and then apply the [Martingale convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems).

You have effectively already shown that $K_n$ is a martingale since (without getting into the background measure theory):

$$\mathbf{E}[|K_n|] = 1 < \infty$$

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[K_n \, | \, K_1,\ldots, K_{n-1}] & = \mathbf{E}[R_{n}K_{n-1} \, |\, K_{n-1}]\\
& = \mathbf{E}[R_n] K_{n-1} \\
& = K_{n-1}
\end{align*}

A particularly simple version of the martingale convergence theorem asserts that if $K_{n}$ is a positive martingale, then it converges almost surely to some $K$: 
$$K_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} K.$$
So we have now established that $K_n$ does converge almost surely to something, it remains to show that $K \equiv 0$.

In an analogy to real analysis: if an infinite product is known to converge (almost surely) to a finite limit, then either the individual terms of the product must converge to $1$, or the limit must be $0$.

Clearly the $R_n$ do not converge almost surely to $1$, hence $K \equiv 0$.

Comment: Neither heuristics nor martingales are needed here.

Answer (score 0):

**Formal answer.** One way to do this (without martingales) is by using [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) and the [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) in tandem. You are flipping a fair coin $n$ times. Let $H_i$ equal $1$ if the coin comes up heads on flip $i$, and $0$ otherwise. Then the $H_i$ are i.i.d. uniform on $\{0, 1\}$, and $S_n = H_1 + ... + H_n$ satisfies:

1. *Strong law of large numbers:* $S_n/n \rightarrow 1/2$ almost surely.
2. *Law of the iterated logarithm:* $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\pm (S_n - n/2)}{\sqrt{2n \log\log n}} = 1/2$ almost surely. (This is because $H_i - 1/2$ has mean $0$ and variance $1/4$ for all $i \geq 1$.)

If we denote your capital after bet $n$ by $K_n$, and your starting capital is $K_0 = 1$, this strategy amounts to betting half your wealth every time. We have the expression $$K_n = K_0 \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{2} + H_i \right) = \frac{3^{S_n}}{2^n},$$

since the denominator is always multiplied by $2$, and the numerator is multiplied by $1$ for every tails and $3$ for every heads. Therefore, we must almost surely have $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} K_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^{S_n}}{2^n} \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^{n/2 + \sqrt{2n \log \log n}/2}}{2^n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{3})^{(n + \sqrt{2n \log \log n})}}{2^n}= 0,$$

which shows that your wealth converges to zero with probability one.

**Informal answer.** Even though you are equally likely to win as to lose this bet on any given round, a loss divides your wealth by 2, while a win only multiplies it by 1.5. This means it takes, on average, $$\log_{1.5}(2) = 1.70951129135...$$ wins to cancel out a loss. But the [SLLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) shows that wins and losses happen with equal frequency asymptotically. Thus, $$K_n \approx K_0 \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{n/2} \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{n/2} = \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)^{n},$$

and the fluctuations in the exponent are only of order $\sqrt{n \log \log n}$ by [LIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm), which is not enough to cancel out the downward exponential decay in the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

This also shows that *any* strategy of the form "On bet $n$, stake $p \%$ of your wealth for fixed $p \in (0, 1)$" must eventually give you a limiting wealth of $0$, because $(1 - p)^{1/2}(1 + p)^{1/2} = (1 - p^2)^{1/2} < 1$, so asymptotically your wealth decays exponentially to zero.